# How can we test invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment in KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder, for FingerprintManager

Tags: android

I'm referring to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

The role of `invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment` isn't clear enough.

```
if {@code false} is passed, the created key will not
be invalidated even if a new fingerprint is enrolled.
The default value is {@code true}, so passing
{@code true} doesn't change the behavior
(the key will be invalidated if a new fingerprint is
enrolled.). Note that this parameter is only valid if
the app works on Android N developer preview.
```

We tested several scenarios. We tested based on different `true`/`false` value in `invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment`. Yes, they both yield the same behavior.

### System already contains Finger 1 record before launching the app

1. The app will only recognize finger 1.

### Trying to add Finger 2 into the system via Settings

1. Close the app.
2. Add finger 2 into the system via Settings
3. Launch the app. The app can recognize both finger 1 and finger 2, regardless the value of `invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment`.

### Trying to remove Finger 1 from the system via Settings

1. Close the app.
2. Remove finger 1 from the system via Settings
3. Launch the app. The app can recognize only recognize finger 2, regardless the value of `invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment`.

Does anyone how can we perform testing, for different value of `invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment`?

Comment: _"The app can recognize both finger 1 and finger 2, regardless the value of invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment."_ The flag controls whether cryptographic keys will be invalidated; there's no invalidation of fingerprints. There's no info in your question about how you manage your keys (e.g. if you keep creating new keys all the time, then obviously you will have a hard time invalidating them).

Comment: Honestly, I have 0 clue on what is the role of "key generation" during finger print recognition, as I don't come across any good documentation explaining this. For the code, I can see `createKey` is being called every time during `onCreate`. Does that mean a new key is created all time? How is it different than new key is only created one time? Is there any impact from end user point of view? Thanks.